# Chromatic number of graph with one odd cycle

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Find chromatic number of graph with only one cycle of odd length. Solution is $3$.
I know that chromatic number of graph that is odd cycle is 3, but how to prove that chromatic number of graph that contains odd cycle is also 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove edges in the cycle, the graph becomes a union of trees.

Comment: And then the rest of graph we can colour with 2 colors right(because it does not have cycle anymore)?

Comment: That's the point, yes.